# "jupyter labextension enable" don't find extension

Tags: docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

when I try to install an extension like hinterland, it don't find the extension

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
RUN conda install --yes jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
RUN conda install --yes jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
RUN jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
RUN jupyter labextension enable hinterland/hinterland   
EXPOSE 8888
ENV JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
```

but if I install it such as nbextension it finds it and work, just like in code below

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
RUN conda install --yes jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
RUN conda install --yes jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
RUN jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
RUN jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland
EXPOSE 8888
```